# How to place Chart templates (.crtx) on a server

Tags: excel, ms-office, powerpoint

I've got a question regarding placement of chart templates on a file server.

I want to do this to avoid having to place the chart template files locally on every PC.
And they will update on all PCs if there is done any changes.

I've only found this to work if I point the "User template"-file location in Word to the specific server location and have a "Chart" folder placed there. This is not a good solution since all users will use the same normal.dotm then..

I've tried to achive this with using "Workgroup templates"-file location to be on the server and have a folder named "Charts" with all the chart templates. But it seems like it only looks for chart templates in the "User template" file location, and not in the "Workgroup templates"-file location.

Is there any other solution to this, so that it's not needed to manually update the chart templates localy on every PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I've discussed this kind of thing with IT folks regarding updateable files for some of my own add-ins, they've always agreed that login scripts to pull down the updated files or group policy to push the updated files out are a pair of reasonable alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I guess this is the way to go then. I just wish it would be a way to make it work with the "Workgroup template"-file location the way it does with the "User template"-location.